# поворот rigidbody за мышью глядя на 3д объект сверху

Tags: unity3d

заблокировал у rigidbody x и z, использую код:

```
            // gives us vector to direction of target
            Vector3 inverseVect = Input.mousePosition;
            // calculate angle by which you have to rotate
            // Note -: This angle is calculated every Frame of FixedUpdate
            float rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(inverseVect.x, inverseVect.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
// Now calculate  rotationVelocity to be applied every frame
            Vector3 rotationVelocity = (Vector3.up * rotationAngle) * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            // Calaculate his delta velocity i.e required - current 
            Vector3 deltavel = (rotationVelocity - rb.angularVelocity);
            // Apply the force to rotate
            rb.AddTorque(deltavel, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

вертиться то в одну то в другую без остановки. на сайтах нашёл - вроде как проверять надо на
 `Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, (Input.mousePosition - transform.position).normalized) > .9f`

но как непойму

Comment: преобразование из мировых в локальные координаты                               // get position of target object
            Vector3 targetPosition = Input.mousePosition;
 // gives us vector to direction of target
            Vector3 inverseVect = transform.InverseTransformPoint(Input.mousePosition);        ограничивает вращение но не указывает на мышь по всему диапазону вращения

Comment: в каком методе у вас код работает?

Answer (score 0):

фуух домучал. 
youtube! 
сам в математике и векторной тоже - ноль, это ппц. хоть разобрался немного.

```
//поворот физикой за мышкой в пустом пространстве 
//(если смотреть на мышь)get right position of mouse if the camera is Perspective
    //подробнее goo.gl/Fc6icj
                Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                float midPoint = (transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position).magnitude * 0.5f;
                Vector3 targetPosition = (mouseRay.origin + mouseRay.direction * midPoint);
    //get position of target object(если смотреть на объект)
                //Vector3 targetPosition = targetObject.transform.position;
    //gives us vector to direction of target
                Vector3 inverseVect = transform.InverseTransformPoint(targetPosition);
    //calculate angle by which you have to rotate.Note: this angle is calculated every Frame of FixedUpdate
                float rotationAngle = Mathf.Atan2(inverseVect.x, inverseVect.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    //Now calculate  rotationVelocity to be applied every frame
                Vector3 rotationVelocity = (Vector3.up * rotationAngle) * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    //Calaculate his delta velocity   i.e required - current 
                Vector3 deltavel = (rotationVelocity - rb.angularVelocity);
    //Apply the force to rotate
                rb.AddTorque(deltavel, ForceMode.Impulse);
    //служ. инфо
                Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, targetPosition, Color.magenta);
                print("targetPosition: " + targetPosition + 
                    " targetObject.transform.position: "+ targetObject.transform.position +
                    " transform.position: "+ transform.position);
```

цель - разобраться, а не под конкретный продукт, поэтому советы по оптимизации принимаются.